# Actualizando el paquete obsoleto de Pandas pd.ewma () a pd.Dataframe.ewm ()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tenía un código que promediaba exponencialmente desde el método pandas `pd.ewma ()`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-d81f5301d1c0> in <module>
     55 
     56     # Smoothing the plot
---> 57     predictions_df_list['ewma'] = pd.ewma(predictions_df_list["prices"], span=20, freq="D") #pd.DataFrame.ewma
     58     predictions_df_list['actual_value'] = test['prices']
     59     predictions_df_list['actual_value_ewma'] = pd.ewma(predictions_df_list["actual_value"], span=20, freq="D")

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'ewma'
```

Me enteré de que el paquete estaba en desuso. Traté de cambiar a `pd.Dataframe.ewm()` pero

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-681b235459d9> in <module>
     55 
     56     # Smoothing the plot
---> 57     predictions_df_list['ewma'] = pd.DataFrame.ewm(predictions_df_list["prices"], span=20) #pd.DataFrame.ewma
     58     predictions_df_list['actual_value'] = test['prices']
     59     predictions_df_list['actual_value_ewma'] = pd.DataFrame.ewm(predictions_df_list["actual_value"], span=20)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3117         else:
   3118             # set column
-> 3119             self._set_item(key, value)
   3120 
   3121     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3192 
   3193         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3194         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3195         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3196 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3385             value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   3386 
-> 3387         elif isinstance(value, Index) or is_sequence(value):
   3388             from pandas.core.series import _sanitize_index
   3389 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\inference.py in is_sequence(obj)
    470 
    471     try:
--> 472         iter(obj)  # Can iterate over it.
    473         len(obj)   # Has a length associated with it.
    474         return not isinstance(obj, string_and_binary_types)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py in __iter__(self)
    184     def __iter__(self):
    185         url = 'https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11704'
--> 186         raise NotImplementedError('See issue #11704 {url}'.format(url=url))
    187 
    188     def _get_index(self, index=None):

NotImplementedError: See issue #11704 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11704
```

Y parece sobre [la pagina de GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11704) que la implementación actual no usa un iterador explícito, sino una ventana deslizante en python y cálculos marginales.

**Por lo tanto, ¿cómo puedo actualizar este método?**